# MessageBox & WM_TIMER (after Win2k)

Tags: winapi

Everyone here knows that from WinXP to user32.dll appeared MessageBoxTimeout API.

But now it's not about using undocumented MessageBoxTimeout, but the use of a documented MessageBox:

so here's a coincidence that from WinXP for any MessageBox - PostMessage (WM_TIMER, 0,0) is equivalent to PostMessage (WM_CLOSE, 0,0).

Question to insiders MS: this is a bug or a feature?

Comment: It is not necessarily a bug, it might be `MessageBox` API specific internal implementation. Why would you want to post a timer event to a window that you don't even own?

Comment: @Roman R.: well, maybe I'm just wondering? And it's not the worst of my sins: in 2011 through PostMessage (GetAncestor (FindWindowEx (HWND_MESSAGE, 0,0,0), GA_PARENT), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0) got BSOD (fixed in 2012: KB2641653 - CVE-2012-0157)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a coincidence. It turns out that `MessageBox` is implemented by a call to `MessageBoxTimeout` which passes a timeout value of `0xFFFFFFFF`. This is trivial to discern using a debugger. And it also turns out that `MessageBoxTimeout` dialogs respond to `WM_TIMER` messages by closing the dialog. That's how `MessageBoxTimeout` implements the timeout.

So, if you post a `WM_TIMER` message to a `MessageBox` dialog you are really posting it to a `MessageBoxTimeout` dialog and so you will indeed close it.

It's certainly not a bug because `MessageBox` makes no promises at all as to how it will respond to receiving `WM_TIMER` messages. And it's not a feature because it's not documented. It's just a curious side-effect of the current implementation of `MessageBox`.

Of course, all this is implementation detail, subject to change, etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks, David! And of course I knew it was not a coincidence :-)